# C# .NET List declaration.Size unknown

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have to declare a list and use it in my code.How ever the number of elements that i will add to list will vary during each time I run my code.So how can I create a list and add elements to it dynamically with out specifying its size during declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("foo");
myList.Add("blah");
// and on and on ...
```

List's in .Net will automatically resize themselves as you add to them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to specify the bounds of a list (as you do with arrays). You can keep on calling Add() method to add elements in the list. You can create either a generic list which takes only specified types of objects and a non-generic list that only takes objects:

**Generic:**

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
intList.Add(10);
intList.Add(20);
```

**Non-Generic:**

```
ArrayList objList = new ArrayList();
objList.Add(New Employee());
objList.Add(20);
objList.Add("string");
```

The later can take any type of object but is not type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The System.Collection namespace is full of collection classes that can dynamically contract and expand its size, see the Generic namespace for the most used classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx

I recommend sticking with a List if you doubt what you are doing:

```
var list = new List<string>();

list.Add("test1");
list.Add("test2");
list.Remove("test1");
```